# What is the default enctype for an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, enctype

Say I've got that form holding some inputs:

```
<form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" >
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I submit this form: which enctype does the browser use?

Is there a well-defined default type?
Or does every browser pick it's own enctype (out of the three allowed ones, of course)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The invalid value default for these attributes is the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` state. **The missing value default for the enctype attribute is also the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` state**. (There is no missing value default for the formenctype attribute.)

— [HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype)

> This attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server (when the value of method is "post"). **The default value for this attribute is "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`".** The value "`multipart/form-data`" should be used in combination with the INPUT element, type="file".

— [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype)

> This determines the mechanism used to encode the form's contents. **It defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.**

— [HTML 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#form)

Answer (score 2):

Default is:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", assuming my source is correct.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)